# Is there a reason the New Testament sometimes says "Christ Jesus" and other times says "Jesus Christ"?

Tags: new-testament

Paul's letters, in particular, seem to switch back and forth between the two. Is there linguistic significance to this? Or is it just a stylistic or translational choice with no greater meaning?

Comment: I'd suggest taking some biblical examples to ground this question as firmly On-Topic, or else it risks getting Closed